# Contacts vs Subscribers in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am really confused between Contacts and Subscribers in SFMC. I know subscribers is used for emailing. What do we use 'Contacts' for ?

Are these 2 separate technical records?

Please advise

Answer (score 7):

"Contacts" are a superset of Subscribers (Email), Mobile Contacts and any other Data Extension you define as a "Root" in Contact Builder. Email Subscribers are automatically added as a Root source of Contacts, as are Mobile Contacts from MobileConnect (SMS), MobilePush and Croup Connect (OTT). All sources of Contacts are tied together through the Contact Key (SubscriberKey in Email). So, if a subscriber has a SubscriberKey of "1" in Email and a Contact Key of "1" in Mobile Connect, the two instances of that individual are associated as being the same Contact.

Answer (score 2):

Hope you´ve resolved your doubt, although, I have searched in trailhead about your issue:

[image]